# Epic Spell Wars rules clarifications

Tags: epic-spell-wars

I have three card clarifications that came up while playing games last night.

**Treasure card "Proton Gem":**

> You may add this card to your spell face up. It counts as a Wild Magic card but is not discarded.

Interpretation 1: Spells are crafted before a round starts. The player places the treasure in place of either a source, quality or delivery card. When the player's spell is revealed the treasure is placed aside and the wild card action takes place.

Rebuttal: The treasure says the player can add it to the spell, but does not specify when.

Interpretation 2: A player composes its spell then when revealed the player adds the treasure to its spell and goes through the wild card action.

Rebuttal: Spells are composed before a round so the treasure can't be added whenever the player wants.

**Delivery card "Nuke-U-Lur Meltdown":**

> 3 damage, and 1 damage to each player adjacent to that foe.

Interpretation 1: The caster is considered a player. If the caster is also adjacent to the target for the caster will take 1 splash damage.
Interpretation 2: The intent of the card would not be to have it damage the caster even if the caster is adjacent to the target.

**Source card "Professor Presto's"**

> If you played a Wild Magic card as part of your spell, gain a treasure.

Interpretation 1: The action of drawing a treasure triggers once even if the player composes its spell with more than one wild magic card.

Interpretation 2: The action of drawing a treasure triggers once for each wild magic card in the player's spell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *You may add this card to your spell face up. It counts as a Wild Magic card but is not discarded.*

1. Everyone with whom I've played has intuitively understood it's added add the same time as the other parts. It should be part of the spell on reveal.

> *3 damage, and 1 damage to each player adjacent to that foe.*

1. There's no reason to believe the caster can't be damaged by this spell. This is hardly the only spell with a drawback.

> *If you played a Wild Magic card as part of your spell, gain a treasure.*

1. Standard board game language. It's not "For each Wild Magic played card as part of your spell, gain a treasure."